# Equation numbering in colab notebook

Tags: latex, tex, google-colaboratory

I'm using 
`\begin{equation}.. \end{equation}` in markdown mode in a Colab notebook and I don't get equation numbering as I would expect from Latex.

Is there a fix for this?

[image: view]

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to use \tag{}, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
y = x \tag{1}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x \tag{1}, \\
g(x) &= x^2 + 2. \tag{2}
\end{align}
```

Comment: The $$ form will work for the first example: `$$ y = x \tag{1} $$`

Comment: How do I get automatic numbered equations ?